# What is correct way to store ASCII string in Javascript without escaping?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am trying store gmaps polyline into a string. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm

The algorithm spits encoded data as ascii starting from ascii 63. Is there a efficient method in javascript that can handle general ascii data unaltered and unescaped

For Eg: A typical encoded polyline looks like this

```
s}`nA{agyMF_CLAFC\{KJ?@_CuDNuCXUDaD|B_DxBaAp@KlCCp@Cr@EnBEdAG`BOvCEv@Ar@HpBZzCfAnKj@pGtAzMbBzO|@lKpBra@JpGErAKz@eEjLg
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "unescaped". Escaping is only necessary when you use string *literals*, to disambiguate characters for the parser. If you generate the data dynamically anyway, escaping won't be possible. But what's the peoblem? Could you please provide an example of what you mean / want? Storing ascii in JS is as simple as `var foo = 'ascii';`

Comment: In this case, since it has single quotes within, it's probably best to do `var foo ="ascii'quotes'inside'will'work";`

Comment: And what exactly is the problem with the example you posted?

Comment: Original problem was the decoded string is not correct. Figured out a way by storing it directly into a collection and reading directly from it. THanks all for the help